# RegExp to find Domain and IP domain in Js

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find domain using regular expression until now I am using

```
var reg_exp_domains = /[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9](?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})+/;
```

that one is working for cases:
    http://www.googlefake.com , 
    http://googlefake.com , etc

but I need to detect for ex http://22.22.22.22/

does someone has some idea?
thank you!

Comment: You can't solve that problem with just a regexp. You don't even handle domains in .co.uk for example.

Comment: ^ and what about `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`? International URLs like `http://домеин.ком/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9](?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})+/`](https://regex101.com/r/kZ9nO1/2)

I've just added the IP-matching part at the beginning. Here are the main parts; they're just repeated:

- `\d{1,3}` Between 1 and 3 digits (0 - 9)
- `|` Logical "OR". So it'll match the IP, OR the normal domain

Note, the IP matching will allow through broken IP addresses. If you need it to be watertight, it is possible but will take more work.

Comment: What about IPV6? :-)

Comment: It's possible. I'll wait for the OP's comment if he wants anything more, though. /shrug/ Thanks though.